# How to use the instr function regardless of ignoring case sensitvitiy of the string. eg: "PENETRATION, Penetration, penetration"

Tags: vba, excel

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1qOo.png)

```
Sub Update_Click()
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 5
  Do Until i > 100  'repeat function below till row 100'

    If InStr(1, (Cells(i, 5).Value), "Struck") > 0 Then  
      Cells(i, 8).Value = "Near miss"
    End If

    If InStr(1, (Cells(i, 5).Value), "Cut") > 0 Then
      Cells(i, 8).Value = "Minor"
    End If

    i = i + 1

  Loop        'close loop formula'
End Sub
```

I would like to search for the words STRUCK, struck, Struck, CUT, Cut, cut

Comment: Please don't use the title as description field for your problem.

Comment: `vbTextCompare` where `instr(1, "A BBB C", "bBb", vbTextCompare)` returns  3

Answer (score 0):

You may change the string to UCase or to LCase. Then compare it, like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print "asd" = "aSd"
    Debug.Print UCase("asd") = UCase("ASD")
    Debug.Print LCase("aSd") = LCase("ASD")

End Sub
```

Ucase:

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/ucase.php

Using the example of Alex K. in the comments, it would be like this:

```
?instr(1, ucase("A BBB C"), ucase("bBb"))
```

if you do not pass optional `vbCompareMethod` argument, which is specified exactly for this.

Comment: @Seyiotuks - well, it should work. But probably with `vbTextCompare` it would be more understandable.

Comment: thank you. what I am trying to do is have the word near miss or minor in a column when certain words are written in another column. regardless of if the certain words are in proper, lower or upper case

Comment: @Seyiotuks - exactly, if you want to disregard the case, you can make all words to `Upper` and then compare the upper values.

Comment: the issue is I cant disregard the case. As I am trying to build a user interative spreadsheet which completes when certain data is input. The issue with most people inputting data is they hardly ever check the "case" the words are typed in. So in effect I cant have it look for upper case for example as I am positive. the user will not always write in upper case. So as stated in my original post the user of the spreadsheet might write Struck, STRUCK or struck in cells(I,5) however I need to be able to cross check for all 3 words and input "minor" in cells(I,8)